# Removing column in pipe delimited file when the text matches with search string

Tags: unix

I need to search for a particular text in pipe separated file and remove the column which matches the text.

ex:
my file

```
1|2|test123|3|4|5....|n
6|7|5|test123|10|11.....|n
6|7|1|9|test123|11.....|n
```

Need to search for column which contains "test" and remove that column

new file should look like

```
1|2|3|4|5....|n
6|7|5|10|11.....|n
6|7|1|9|11.....|n
```

I have tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2=$3="";gsub(/[|]+/,"|")}1' test.txt >> test5.txt
```

command where column number is explicitly hardcoded but need a script which would search for the text and then remove the column.

Answer (score 0):

All the examples use the data file:

```
1|2|test123|3|4|5....|n
6|7|5|test123|10|11.....|n
6|7|1|9|test123|11.....|n
test|1|2|3|4|5......|n
1|2|3|4|5|6.....|n-test-n
1|2|test|and-test-again|3|4|5|6.....|n-test-n
```

There are at least two ways to approach this.  One is purely textual: replace a sequence pipe, zero or more non-pipes, the word 'test', zero or more non-pipes, and another pipe with a single pipe:

```
awk '{ gsub(/\|[^|]*test[^|]*\|/, "|"); print }' test.txt >> test5.txt
```

Output:

```
1|2|3|4|5....|n
6|7|5|10|11.....|n
6|7|1|9|11.....|n
test|1|2|3|4|5......|n
1|2|3|4|5|6.....|n-test-n
1|2|and-test-again|3|4|5|6.....|n-test-n
```

Given that the word 'test' can appear in the first or last columns, you have to work harder to deal with those:

```
awk '{ gsub(/\|[^|]*test[^|]*\|/, "|");  # Middle
       gsub(/^[^|]*test[^|]*\|/, "");    # Start
       gsub(/\|[^|]*test[^|]*$/, "");    # End
       print }' test.txt >> test5.txt
```

Output:

```
1|2|3|4|5....|n
6|7|5|10|11.....|n
6|7|1|9|11.....|n
1|2|3|4|5......|n
1|2|3|4|5|6.....
1|2|and-test-again|3|4|5|6.....
```

And given that `test` can appear in adjacent fields, you have to scan twice for the 'middle' pattern.

```
awk '{ gsub(/\|[^|]*test[^|]*\|/, "|");  # Middle - 1
       gsub(/\|[^|]*test[^|]*\|/, "|");  # Middle - 2
       gsub(/^[^|]*test[^|]*\|/, "");    # Start
       gsub(/\|[^|]*test[^|]*$/, "");    # End
       print }' test.txt >> test5.txt
```

Output:

```
1|2|3|4|5....|n
6|7|5|10|11.....|n
6|7|1|9|11.....|n
1|2|3|4|5......|n
1|2|3|4|5|6.....
1|2|3|4|5|6.....
```

The other way scans through the fields of each line, not printing those that contain 'test'.

```
awk -F '|' \
    '{ pad = "";
       for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
       {
         if ($i !~ /test/)
         {
           printf("%s%s", pad, $i);
           pad = "|";
         }
       }
       print "";
     }' test.txt >> test5.txt
```

Output:

```
1|2|3|4|5....|n
6|7|5|10|11.....|n
6|7|1|9|11.....|n
1|2|3|4|5......|n
1|2|3|4|5|6.....
1|2|3|4|5|6.....
```

Comment: awk -F '|' \
    '{ pad = "";
       for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
       {
         if ($i !~ /test/)
         {
           printf("%s%s", pad, $i);
           pad = "|";
         }
       }
       print "";
     }' in this code where do i pass the i/p file name?

Comment: After the end of the script, so after the closing single quote.  You have `awk <options> <script> <files>` (in general).  I have now updated the answer to include your file name and output redirection.

Comment: excellent works fine. I also need to remove the next column after the ith column i.e column which has "Test"

Comment: So when you detect `test` in the version with the loop, skip the next column too by incrementing `i` in the (newly added) `else` clause to the `if` statement: `else i++`.  That leads to a double increment, skipping the following column too.  You can do it with the `gsub()` code too, but it is messier (and what happens if test appears in the last column?).

Comment: as per requirement test wont be a last column. can you please give me the entire code snipet with next column logic.

Comment: @elvisthom: I wrote the `else` statement for you in my previous comment.  There's only one `if` statement in the script.  What's the ambiguity that causes you difficulty?  You need to be able to take answers given to you and make simple extensions to them.  Also, extending the question after it has been answered is not really fair on those who answer.

Answer (score 0):

file.txt

```
1|2|test123|3|4|5....|n
6|7|5|test123|10|11.....|n
6|7|1|9|test123|11.....|n
```

Script:

```
sed 's/test123|//' file.txt >> file1.txt
```

Comment: Nit picking: only removes columns which contain `test123` instead of just `test`; doesn't remove them when `test123` (or `test`) is not at the end of the field; doesn't remove the whole field when there are extra characters other than `test123` (or `test`) in the field; doesn't remove it from the last field on the line.